# Implementing a good C++0x error_condition?

Tags: exception, boost, error-handling, boost-asio, c++11

**I try to figure out how the new `system_error` together with `error_code`, `error_category` and not the least the (meant to implement *portable* error reporting) `error_condition` should be used.**

I think by reading [boost.system](http://en.highscore.de/cpp/boost/errorhandling.html) I understand how I should use `error_codes` and `error_category`. The description leaves out how this is used in conjunction when throwing an exception with ´system_error`, but from the interface from that class I can guess.

```
class system_error : public runtime_error {
public:
  // [...]
  system_error(error_code ec, const string& what_arg);
  system_error(int ev, const error_category& ecat, const string& what_arg);
  system_error(int ev, const error_category& ecat);
  // [...]
```

So, I throw a `system_error`-exception with the right `int`+`error_category` or `error_code` with its `error_category()`-method.

**But whats the way to provide the *portable* interface with `error_condition`?**

Both `error_code` *and* `error_category` both have method `default_error_condition`:

```
class error_category {
public:
  // [...]
  virtual error_condition default_error_condition(int ev) const noexcept;
  // [...]

class error_code {
public:
  // [...]
  error_condition default_error_condition(int ev) const noexcept;
  // [...]
```

The `error_category`-Instances should be pre-created, for example (*user-code*):

```
struct AppCategory : public error_category { 
  const char *name() const noexcept override {
    return "application"; } 
  string message(int ev) const override {
    switch(ev) {
      case 14: return "error message";
      default: return "???";
    }
  } 
  error_condition default_error_condition(int ev) const noexcept override {
     ... ??? ...
  }
};
```

My questions implementing this:

- Should I implement `default_error_condition` in `error_category`, and how?
- Or how do I connect `error_codes` to the proper `error_conditions`,
- and should I pre-construct `error_condition` instances?
- A class `error_code` is not supposed to be provided by the user (me), right?

**Is there a good example where I can take a look at code how `error_condition` is supposed to be extended by the user**, in conjunction with `system_error`-exceptions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the error codes for your error category can be mapped to one of the `std::errc` error codes then `default_error_condition` should do that mapping, and return a `std::error_condition` with a category of `std::generic_category()` and a value of the corresponding `std::errc` enum value. Otherwise it should return an `error_condition` referring to that category.

Comment: If I have a set of error conditions from my multi platform application , how should they be thrown?  From the documentation it seems strange to put them in a `system_error` as that carries a platform dependent `error_code`.  For example, I have a `enum` that is specified as `is_error_condition_enum` and I have an `error_category` that matches those error conditions.  Do I need to create an exception that carries an `error_condition` in this case?

Comment: You could create a new exception type: see for example `std::future_error` which is specific to the futures API.

Comment: Thanks.  That's a great reference.  Also thanks for all the work you have done on `this::thread`, `boost::thread` and `std::thread`.  They are pure win.